# Yii Project Setup on Remote Server

Tags: php, yii, remote-access

I've inherited an application written using the Yii PHP framework. I've uploaded all the project files to a remote server, but I don't have SSH access or shell-exec permission.

Is it possible to make the application work in these circumstances?

If so, what files do I need to edit and in what way please?

Comment: With what kind of a problem exactly you are facing? Have You configured a web server?

Comment: Yes, I've uploaded the files to a directory on the same server where I host my blog. I could also work locally using ampps. My issue is I don't have the overview-knowledge to even know if its possible to simply "upload and go" (perhaps with a few configuration tweaks) or whether I need to go through some complex installation porcedure. I think Yii uses composer to install, but once that's done, does the project become "portable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be portable, all you need is just copy all project contents (including dependencies) to the destination folder and make proper [configuration for a web-server](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#configuring-web-servers).

The only one issue here is `@app/runtime` and `@app/web/assets` folders -- the should be accessible to write for web-process (the second is only if you are using AssetManager).

You can solve this issue in config, using [`runtimePath`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#$runtimePath-detail) and [`assetManager['basePath']`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$basePath-detail) parameters.

Comment: I'm out of my depth here. On my remote server I get the default "congratulations" page at http://robinandrews.uk/dev/speaking/frontend/web/ but on localhost on ampps I jest get "HI". No idea in either case where I should navigate to get the app working.  The project files are here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8phrlwueu7vbe9/speaking.rar?dl=0 if anyone willing to help more.

Comment: @Robin the problem is somewhere in your local environment, not in the project itself. I just downloaded your project and started php server with `php -S localhost:8080` from `speaking/fontend/web` folder -- works fine

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me too. I did that and navigated to http://localhost:8080/speaking and there it was!